# Правильная обработка идемпотентных методов в REST API

Tags: rest

Спецификация по методам HTTP [явно говорит](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2) о том, что метод DELETE является идемпотентным, и, значит, он должен выдавать идентичный вывод для любого количество вызовов. В то же время, насколько понимаю, хорошим тоном в REST является вернуть только что удаленную сущность, чтобы клиент мог вывести смешное подтверждающее сообщение, сформировав ее на основе этой сущности, а на все последующие запросы он должен возвращать no content или not found. Соответственно, все сводится к банальному вопросу: по существующим негласным соглашениям мне стоит всегда отдавать no content или все-таки выводить сущность при реальном удалении?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если дочитать кусок спецификации?

> It knows that repeating
>      the request will have the same intended effect, even if the original
>      request succeeded, though **the response might differ**.

Т. е.

> Он [клиент] знает, что запрос приведёт к тому же результату, даже если первый запрос завершился успешно, хотя **ответ может быть другим**.

Речь не о идентичном выводе, а об одинаковом результате - в твоём случае это "объект удалён и больше не существует".